# Opt out from job search notifications for results not provided by SO Jobs directly?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, notifications

I had a saved job search on Jobs, which almost never brought any results up because sadly Stack Overflow Jobs has not made any impact so far in the country I live.

I left the search up because I wanted to see if at any time the local job market would warm up to the service (which I would like, because I'm generally not very happy with the existing solutions).

For good or for worse, since a few days back Stack Overflow has come to an arrangement with the biggest player in the job search segment here in Spain (InfoJobs), and are now publishing their offers in Jobs.

Now I'm receiving notifications for job alerts I'm not interested in. If I wanted to receive job offers from Infojobs, I can easily configure it over there.

I'd like to keep the job search notifications up, but only for offers that are actually published here, not for syndicated content.

<sup><sub>**(To be able to differentiate real results from syndicated results in the search results would be very useful as well, but I acknowledge that that's a different issue).**</sub></sup>

Comment: I’m interested in employers that would use SO as a recruiting platform. If SO sends me results from employers not using this site, is both redundant and  noisy. It’s not a “beef”; it’s a request for greater granularity in notification settings.

Comment: For me, the idea is that the quality of the jobs here on SO is better. For the rest of the jobs, there are other bigger sites. Convenient to sort them, but this does not sound like a great marketing idea, unfortunately.

Comment: I just got an email on a job search like yours. The offer is ridiculous, they are looking for a full slack (yes, full slack) developer that knows electricity and electronics, UI design, C++, to visit clients all over the region... I won't even mention the salary, it just doesn't matter. I have unsubscribed from all job alerts of course. Good luck.

Comment: @HansPassant InfoJobs is a low quality barrel scrapping tool for job search, with dozens of misstagged content, no visible moderation and duplicated ( if not more times ) content. I can easily understand why someone would like to not be notified of that.