# Seeing a lot of jobs from India - What just happened?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I just noticed that there are a lot of job postings from India. Many of them are very new (< 1 hour). Filtering the job postings with India (within 20 km) gave like 5000 jobs.

- What just happened?
- Has there been any change is the job posting policy?
- Are all these legitimate jobs posted by employers themselves?

**EDIT**
Clicking on *Apply* takes you to the job site Indeed.

Comment: Oh man jobs are showing from my hometown also, companies which are completely unprofessional and have pathetic pay grade are also listed. LOL.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378194/what-would-be-the-point-of-sending-users-over-to-linkedin

Comment: [Also related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379721/opt-out-from-job-search-notifications-for-results-not-provided-by-so-jobs-direct).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The jobs you found are being syndicated from Indeed.

As part of our efforts to grow the job board globally, especially in regions we don't have a large sales presence, we're experimenting with syndication partnerships. We currently have a few of these partnerships going (e.g. with InfoJobs in Spain and Indeed in both India and Japan).

"More jobs" is a constant theme in the feedback we hear from users on Stack Overflow Jobs. Users from India represent one of the largest sources of traffic on Jobs; however, we only had approximately 20 jobs across the country prior to this partnership.

We recognize that there are legitimate concerns in growing the job board via partnerships, especially around maintaining quality and being transparent about which jobs are syndicated. To answer your specific questions:

> Has there been any change is the job posting policy?

Our current job posting policy continues to apply even to syndicated listings. We work closely with our partners in filtering & prioritizing listings as much as possible before they get to our job board. However, given the volumes, there's a chance that lower quality listings do make it through.

To address this, we've invested in better automation & matching. We're improving our tools that automatically filter out low quality listings, and we're continually improving our job targeting algorithm which powers job ads, search, and matches. We're also paying close attention to listings flagged by the community; we review every single reported listing and use this data to train our algorithms.

> Are all these legitimate jobs posted by employers themselves?

Yes. All of these jobs are supposed to be legitimate, posted by the employers themselves on the partner site. Listings from third-party staffing agencies are being filtered out by our syndication partners. If you do come across a listing that breaks our policy, please report it so that we can take it down, work with our partners to block similar content, and improve our quality filters.

> Clicking on Apply takes you to the job site Indeed

We've heard this in user feedback around syndicated listings in general. We're working on a feature that clearly labels syndicated listings so that it'll be more transparent.