# I'm receiving only jobs for Japan and India

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm from Brazil and from few months ago to now I only recive job alerts for Japan and India.

I've selected to receive alerts of C# and RoR positions.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem: the only job alerts I get these days are for Japan and India. The ones from Japan are especially annoying, since I can't even *read* these (I cannot read Japanese).

I suspect this is because [they recently started aggregating jobs from LinkedIn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378194/what-would-be-the-point-of-sending-users-over-to-linkedin) and [Indeed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391565/seeing-a-lot-of-jobs-from-india-what-just-happened) (and other bottom-barrel services in other countries, like [InfoJobs in Spain](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/31/stack-overflow-infojobs-bringing-opportunities-to-developers-in-spain/)). Obviously, they aren't getting enough genuine job listings of their own through the platform, so they've just become a repeater for other job boards.

If they had enough of their own genuine listings, a few thrown in from other sources would perhaps be acceptable, but since they don't have any of their own genuine listings, pretty much the only emails you (and I) are getting are for these syndicated listings, which means our inboxes are just full of noise.

I had really wanted Stack Overflow Jobs to be a success. There was a lot of promise in the mission. However, I think it's quite clear that it is not going to be successful. The above-linked answers from Jobs team members admit as much. Almost a month now, and still the feature promised by Puneet to "clearly label syndicated listings so that it'll be more transparent" is missing in action. One must be forgiven for concluding that this is because it's not a good indicator of the platform's health if *all* of your job listings are labeled as "syndicated".

I think it's time to turn off Jobs alerts, since there's nothing useful coming through that pipe anymore. If you're anything like me, you get enough noise in your email inbox already. You might as well just use LinkedIn and Indeed directly. At least they let you filter out jobs whose listings are in languages that you do not speak.

A feature [was requested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379721/opt-out-from-job-search-notifications-for-results-not-provided-by-so-jobs-direct) almost a year ago now to allow you to opt in only to email notifications for non-syndicated Jobs, but only crickets can be heard there.

Answer (score 4):

Flávio sorry for the delay. I'm a developer on the Talent/Jobs product.

I checked your saved search and saw that your filters are:

- Tags (Tech you like): `ruby-on-rails`
- Free text search: C#

These are 2 different filters, and therefore the search algorithm will try to find the jobs that have the tag `ruby-on-rails` **and** that have in their text C#. Unfortunately, most of the jobs that match those 2 filters are indeed Japanese jobs from a syndication partner.

If you would like to receive alerts about RoR or C# jobs, I would suggest picking both as tag filters and leaving the free text search empty.

Additionally, I saw that you haven't set any desired work location in your job preferences (Account > Edit profile and settings > Job preferences). What this means is that the location targeting filter that each job has will not apply. Most of the japanese jobs that are included in your current alert are not remote, and targeted for candidates in Japan, but as you haven't selected any desired work location, the algorithm assumes that you can work anywhere.

I would suggest setting up the "where you'd like to work" preference, with the place where you live ("Always include your current location") and any other place where you would be willing to relocate (if applicable). This won't filter out remote jobs, as this filter is not applied to the job's location, but to the job's targeting locations (where the company accepts candidates from). Remote jobs usually are targeted worldwide.

Comment: How do I set it up to indicate that I'm willing to relocate anywhere in the US or any other country that speaks English as a primary language? Do I have to enter all of those locations manually? Does that mean every city?

Comment: SO Jobs doesn't support language based desired work locations. However, job location targeting is at a country level, so if you have any US based location in your desired work locations, that should be enough to be matched with jobs that target the US. If you want to restrict the results to certain area, you can use the location search filter with a radius.