# Add ability to filter on- and off-site listings on Jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

How can I filter the job listing based on direct company jobs and other job recruiting sites? The job site has been a mess after too many listings.

It is also better to save a search item when filtered through companies using locations.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379721/opt-out-from-job-search-notifications-for-results-not-provided-by-so-jobs-direct).